# Image Overflowing Grid Cell

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a very simple code with a grid and one image item within. The grid should be 70% of height of screen and I anticipated that the image is going to be contained within. For some reason, the image overflows.

The code:

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-2 w-full h-[70vh] items-center bg-[#19486A] border-2 border-red-400">
    <img src={homeImage_desktop} alt='' className='ml-auto' />
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of image overflowing grid]

I can resize the image manually to `70vh` but I'd rather have the image resize itself to fit the parent automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `max-h-full max-w-full min-w-0 min-h-0`

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-2 w-full h-[70vh] items-center bg-[#19486A] border-2 border-red-400">
  <img class="max-h-full max-w-full min-w-0 min-h-0 ml-auto" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643131747793-1b103cc66c6b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1036&q=80" alt='' />
</div>
```

Comment: Best answer to address dynamically resizing images in css grid. Essentially, every img must have 1) `min-height: 0` and `max-width: 100%`,  2) every grid container under the parent must have `min-height: 0` set, and 3) the immediate grid containers parents of the img must also have `min-width: 0` for the `align-` and `justify-` properties to work

Answer (score 0):

Set the image to 100% width of its parent element

```html
 <div className="grid grid-cols-2 w-full h-[70vh] items-center bg-[#19486A] border-2    border-red-400">
     <img className="w-full" src={homeImage_desktop} alt='' className='ml-auto' />
 </div>
```

Comment: And add `object-contain` class on the image so it doesn't stretch